# JavaScript: How to abort unload and making a JavaScript call?

Tags: javascript, jquery, onunload

I'd like to make at evere onunload event a jQuery call which toggles a few divs in one second. And then I'd like to do the unload.

How can I time out the unload for one second and make a jQuery call in this time?

Thanks for help!

Flo

EDIT:

Ok, I think, the most passable solution is instead of an usual link every link gets a javascript call like this:

```
<a href="link('http://google.ch')">Google</a>
```

And the Function link:

```
function link(param) {
    //Here a for loop to toggle all the divs what I wanted before...
    window.location=param;
}
```

But thanks for help ;)

Comment: Not sure what you want to do here, to call something once in a seconds time use setTimeout(function() {}, 1000); and every second setInterval(function() {}, 1000);

Comment: I want to toggle a div close before unload, so it looks better. And to do the slideToggle, I need one second time before the page unloads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`beforeunload`'s event can only be halted with a blocking action such as `alert()`, `prompt()`, etc...

So if you tried to call a function in that event, it is most likely the browser will simply ignore it.